How properly write TypeScript callback function when it uses type "never"?
I'm using Pinia with TypeScript and facing this error:

Vue: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

My code is:
getters: {
    isInProcess: (state) => {
        return (identification: string, exact: boolean = true) : boolean => {
            return exact ? state.inProcess.includes(identification) : state.inProcess.some((x: []) => x.includes(identification));
        };
    },
},

The error occurs on .includes(identification)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you don't get enough engagement here, consider [edit]ing the code to be a [mre] that doesn't depend on vue/pinia. Or, if it really does depend on those, you might still want to make the code a [mre] others can just copy and paste into their IDEs; right now this is just an excerpt and if people look at it there are all kinds of errors unrelated to your question.

It sounds like you didn't fully define the type for inProcess.  Maybe it's only defined as an array, but what kind of array?  array of strings?  array of arrays?  not clear from the code given.  See this similar question
